# how to refresh page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to parse JSON file and display on view .I am using Ionic framework with AngularJS .I am able to parse the JSON file .But I am facing one issue that page is not refresh after click of button .I will explain the problem in other words .I have four or 4 tabs ("A", "RE", "d", "N") in my main view.When I click **"Re"** it displays the data of "RE" tab , but data is collapse mean all texts are collapse why ? but when I inspect the page (right click of mouse) .it atomically look good as I want why ? how to refresh page so it look same as it look after inspect.

Points to reproduce issue

- Run the plunker .click **"Re" tab** it show text but text is collapsible (text is collide each other)
- when you inspect element after click right mouse button .it show text is correct format why ? why it not showing previously ?

here is my code

```
 function callTestSuccess(obj){



            $scope.checkedCount=3;
            console.log($scope.checkedItems)
        }
```

Comment: but did u understood the reason as why the problem was solved by ng-if?

Comment: because ng-if reload the contend. mean it remove and add contend from dom.but if I used ng-show it only hide and show in dom (contend remain in dom)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
$route.reload();
```

Please check this [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution I used **ng-show** .If I used **ng-if** intead of **ng-show** it works perfectly